# Launch WPF application using Process.Start

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I am attempting to launch a **wpf application** using `Process.Start`. When I launch the process by double-clicking it in `explorer.exe`, it launches properly; however, when I try to use the following code snippet:

```
var programPath = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Program Directory\program.exe";
if(!File.Exists(programPath))
{
     MessageBox.Show("The program.exe file does not exist! Cannot launch.");
     return;
}
Process.Start(programPath);
```

My WPF process flashes in the task manager briefly before immediately closing.

Comment: does your application crashes? just see application logs in windows....

Comment: @dbw I'm not sure if it crashes or not, but I'm fairly certain it shouldn't given I can launch it just fine on its own...

Comment: Does your application depend on other files in the working folder? if so, make sure do add that information to the Start() method

Comment: if your APp is crashing then handle App_DispatcherUnhandledException.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed the problem this way:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = programPath;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(programPath);
proc.Start();
```

The trick was to set the working directory to the path of the WPF application, rather than the working directory of the launching application.

Comment: Is this specific to your program? What happens if you run it with an invalid working directory via some other method (such as creating a shortcut and then changing the path or running it from a cmd)